# Troca de vetor de chars com problema

Tags: c++, struct

Estou tentando ordenar este vetor de struct que possui valores int aleatórios e um vetor de char também com valores aleatórios. Mas me deparei com um problema. A ideia é ordena-los a partir dos números aleatórios e as letras devem acompanhar a mudança de posição dos números dentro do vetor de struct. Antes os números mudavam de posição e as letras não. Desta forma está quase funcional, porém as letras não são impressas de maneira corretas. Gostaria de entender onde as letras estão sendo perdidas. O código segue abaixo. Desde já agradeço!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

struct Jogador {
    char nome[5];
    int pontuacao;
};

void troca(int &a, int &b, char c[], char d[]) {
    int temp;
    char temp1[5];

temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c[i] = temp1[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c[i] = d[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    d[i] = temp1[i];
}

}

void selectionSort(Jogador jogador[], int tamanhoVetor) {
int imin;
for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor - 1; i++) {
   imin = i;
  for(int j = i + 1; j < tamanhoVetor; j++)
     if(jogador[j].pontuacao < jogador[imin].pontuacao)
        imin = j;
  troca(jogador[i].pontuacao, jogador[imin].pontuacao, jogador[i].nome, jogador[imin].nome);
 }
}


Jogador criarVetor(Jogador jogador[], int tamanhoVetor) {

for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        jogador[i].nome[j] = rand() % 26 + 65;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
    jogador[i].pontuacao = rand() % 100000 + 1;
}

return jogador[tamanhoVetor];

}

int main() { 

srand(time(NULL));

int tamanhoVetor;

while(true) {
    std::cout << "Tamanho do vetor: ";
    std::cin >> tamanhoVetor;
    if(tamanhoVetor < 1001 && tamanhoVetor > 0) {
        break;
    }
}

Jogador jogador[tamanhoVetor];

jogador[tamanhoVetor] = criarVetor(jogador, tamanhoVetor);

std::cout << std::endl;

for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
    std::cout << "Jogador[" << i << "] = ";
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        std::cout << jogador[i].nome[j];
    }
    std::cout << " e " << jogador[i].pontuacao << std::endl;
}

std::cout << std::endl;

selectionSort(jogador, tamanhoVetor);

for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
    std::cout << "Jogador[" << i << "] = ";
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        std::cout << jogador[i].nome[j];
    }
    std::cout << " e " << jogador[i].pontuacao << std::endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema consiste em um simples erro de atribuição na função troca(). No primeiro for dentro da função você fez

```
c[i] = temp1[i];
```

quando na verdade você deveria fazer

```
temp1[i] = c[i];
```

Da primeira forma você sobrescreveu o parâmetro da função com um array não inicializado. Esse era o motivo de aparecerem nomes errados e repetidos na saída

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Pequeno detalhe que faz toda a diferença, vou prestar mais atenção nisso hehehe.